# There is already an object named 'Position' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Создаю простейшую SQL таблицу в VSCode, заполняю  ее и добавляю в нее данные:

```
CREATE TABLE Position (
    ID_Position int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Position_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Salary int NOT NULL,
    Experience int NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO Position 
VALUES (1, 'Seller', 500, 2);

INSERT INTO Position
VALUES (2, 'Security', 400, 1);

INSERT INTO Position
VALUES (3, 'Cashier', 600, 3);

SELECT * FROM Position;
```

Однако почему-то `Position` подчеркивает красным и пишет: `There is already an object named 'Position' in the database.` Погуглив, понял, что в основном проблема в том, что все делается в `master`, а надо в другой. Однако я открываю окно выбора баз данных, и вижу там только эти: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с этой проблемой, что делать? Пробовал обновлять кэш, но все равно не помогало.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в базе уже есть таблица `Position` - конкретно об этом говорится в ошибке

Comment: В master, конечно, не стоит писать. Создайте свою базу данных: [create database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) и работайте с ней.